# Testing lazy loading in hibernate (java spring with transactions)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, spring-transactions

I have following setup:
Two entities (Parent, Child), the children should be lazy loaded in the parent which works just fine by extending the `JpaRepository` with a custom repository `ParentCustomRepository` and calling `Hibernate.initialize`. The following code works as expected.

```java
@Entity(name = "children")
public class Child {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    @Column
    private String name;

    // Getter and Setter...
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "parents")
public class Parent {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "parent",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Child> children;

    @Column
    private String name;

    // Getter and Setter...
}
```

```java
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {}
```

```java
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long>, ParentCustomRepository {}
```

```java
public interface ParentCustomRepository {
    List<Parent> findAllWithChildren();
}
```

```java
@Transactional
@Component
public class ParentCustomRepositoryImpl implements ParentCustomRepository {

    private final ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public ParentCustomRepositoryImpl(ParentRepository parentRepository) {
        this.parentRepository = parentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Parent> findAllWithChildren() {
        final List<Parent> parents = this.parentRepository.findAll();
        parents.forEach(parent -> {
            Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChildren());
        });
        return parents;
    }
}
```

So far so good. However, I can't get the tests to work in an **acceptable** way. I want to have tests which are independent from each other in a way that there is no need for a fresh context for each test. Here is a simple test class which does to show what I mean.

```java
@SpringBootTest
// @Transactional // uncomment this line to enable auto rollback after each test.
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ExampleTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository childRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        if (parentRepository.count() > 0) {
            LOG.info("Already Set Up");
            return;
        }

        LOG.info("Set Up");

        Parent christian = new Parent();
        christian.setName("Christian");

        christian = parentRepository.save(christian);

        Child alex = new Child();
        alex.setName("Alex");
        alex.setParent(christian);

        alex = childRepository.save(alex);

        Child daniela = new Child();
        daniela.setName("Daniela");
        daniela.setParent(christian);

        daniela = childRepository.save(daniela);

        christian.setChildren(Arrays.asList(alex, daniela));

        // commit transaction when using @Transactional 
    }


    @Test
    public void givenStoredParent_whenGetAllChildren_thenCorrectSize() {
        checkSize();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenStoredParent_whenGetAllChildren_thenCorrectSize_secondTime() {
        checkSize();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenStoredParent_whenAddChild_thenUpdatedSize() {
        addChild();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenStoredParent_whenAddChild_thenUpdatedSize_secondTime() {
        addChild();
    }

    public void addChild() {
        assertThat(childRepository.count()).isEqualTo(2);

        final List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.findAllWithChildren();
        assertThat(parents.size()).isEqualTo(1);

        Parent christian = parents.get(0);
        assertThat(christian.getChildren().size()).isEqualTo(2);

        Child peter = new Child();
        peter.setName("Peter");
        peter.setParent(christian);

        childRepository.saveAndFlush(peter);

        assertThat(childRepository.count()).isEqualTo(3);

        assertThat(childRepository.findAll()).allMatch(child -> {
            return child.getParent().getName().equals("Christian");
        });

        final List<Parent> updatedParents = parentRepository.findAllWithChildren();
        assertThat(updatedParents.size()).isEqualTo(1);

        christian = updatedParents.get(0);
        assertThat(christian.getChildren().size()).isEqualTo(3);
    }

    public void checkSize() {
        final List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.findAllWithChildren();
        assertThat(parents.size()).isEqualTo(1);

        Parent christian = parents.get(0);
        assertThat(christian.getChildren().size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
}
```

- If I run these tests **without** the `@Transactional` annotation, every `save` operation persists the changes in the database, which then leads to different results in the remaining tests.

  - I know that I could just clear the database after each test in a tearDown method annotated with `@AfterEach`. This would result in a clean start for every test and seems quite fine for this example. However, the application I am developing for my company depends on a much larger initialized database which would take quite some time for hundreds of tests. (This is also the case why I do **not** want to use `@DirtiesContext` anywhere in the tests)
- If I run these tests **with**  the `@Transactional` annotation, a rollback is executed after each test. This is actually the behavior I am looking for. As you can see in the results of the test output, some tests fail. This is because `childRepository.save(peter)` wont persist the added child and hence a call to `parentRepository.findAllWithChildren() will only return the children which are in the database since the beginning.

  - I know that I could just persist the transaction via a commit, but then I would not have independent tests anymore.
  - Using `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)` in the test class does not work. As I do not want to use this isolation level in the actual program code I did not do some further researches in this direction.

My assumption is that I **need** a `commit` before I could access the updated relationship between the parent and its children. A commit also clears all savepoints and hence I can not execute a rollback even with a custom transaction management.

As I have spent days searching for a solution that satisfies my needs and did not succeed, I kindly ask if some of you have already dealt with this kind of problem and could provide a solution and or explanation. Is there some best practice I am not aware of?

Alex

Comment: Why do you want to test if spring repository works? thats a core feature of the framework and you dont need to test if it persists stuff into db... I would just write single test that checks if spring context is initialized and beans are available and can read something from prepopulated db. Whats the benefit for testing if "save" works?

Comment: @Nadir These code snippets are just an example, of course I do not just want to test if save works. The actual tests are much more complicated.

Comment: Then why just not mock the repository beans?

Comment: @Nadir When I mock the repository beans the relationship between the parent and its children does only exist when I manually add them to the list. Sounds good for this example, but in a bigger application this would result in a lot of complex mocked beans. Actually, I'm looking for a simple solution but I am afraid there is no such solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an @AfterEach method, where you restore the initial database (eg. you remove added rows if they exist, etc.).

Comment: This would need the knowledge of the logic in more complex methods. If developer A writes the test and developer B writes the code, developer A still needs to know which rows are added/removed/updated to be able to proceed the restore in an afterEach method.

Comment: You invoke `peter.setParent(christian);` but what about `christian.setChildren(christian.getChildren().add(peter))` ?

Comment: This is one of the features of hibernate. I do not need to explizit set its children, this means that I do not have to save the parent again. When a child is saved and I fetch the parent I automatically get all children.